# Playback problem on Firefox or Chrome at Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, firefox, google-chrome, playback

I'm encountering a playback issue on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and would appreciate some guidance.

When attempting to watch online videos on both Chrome and Firefox from various websites, I encounter a problem where the video fails to play, and the loading circle on the screen keeps rotating. Notably, my internet connection is stable.

Restarting my laptop temporarily resolves the issue, allowing smooth video playback for about 30–40 minutes. However, the problem reoccurs after this timeframe.

I've already tried updating both Chrome and Firefox, as well as ensuring that my graphics drivers are up-to-date, but the issue persists. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Sounds like a networking, or Out-Of-Memory problem. How are you connected to the network? How much RAM and swap do you hsve? The terminal commands `service NetworkManager status;ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'` and `free` will help determine further action. Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour]. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: By networking if you mean Internet connection then I am using Wi-Fi. I have 8gb ram. And I have 500 GB SSD which has more than 300 GB available space. 
(I am an amateur. So please don't laugh if I am saying anything silly. But my problem still continues)

Comment: Do you have an example of a video that fails to load? What CPU does your machine have? Is any error messages shown if you bring up developer console (press F12 in Firefox)?

Comment: Here I tried to add a link for the screencast of my problem. Hopefully it'll make clear to understand.
"https://www.kapwing.com/videos/657ff1246794d12566feca60"

Comment: So the video loads. That precludes network failures. I think we won't get any further unless you press F12 and show us the developer console log.

Comment: Here I tried to show console log and network log. I don't know it understandable or not:
"https://www.kapwing.com/videos/6580a4f2f67dd44c776e4e8f"

Comment: And also, I have tried with disabling the ad blocker and restart the browser. Still same problem!